# How to pass ctx argument to own function?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

It isn't exactly my code but similar example:
Function body:

```
async def fun(fun_word)
  ctx.send(fun_word)
```

Then main code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
msg = message.content
if msg=="pancake"
  fun(word)
```

I have tried many ways to pass **ctx** argument to function, but none of them worked.
Is any solution for this?

Comment: please provide the solutions you've tried. you can pass ctx as an argument or global variable -- commonly within a class as a property

Comment: I mean I have tried fun(word, ctx), but ctx was flaged as undefined name. As I know ctx can't be defined in on_message, can it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Await the function**

You need to `await` the function. "Calling" a coroutine actually does nothing.

```py
async def fun(fun_word):
    ctx.send(fun_word)
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    msg = message.content
    if msg == "pancake":
        await fun(word)
```

---

**Making context on the fly (albeit incomplete)**

See the docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context#discord.ext.commands.Context. You can make your own context off the message given.

```py
async def fun(ctx, fun_word):
    ctx.send(fun_word)
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    msg = message.content
    if msg == "pancake":
        await fun(commands.Context(message=message), word)
```

---

**Send the message normally**

This is the cleanest way of achieving what you appear to want to do. Rather than forcing `ctx`, just send the message normally through `message.channel`. In fact, `ctx.send` is actually just an alias to this.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    msg = message.content
    if msg == "pancake":
        await message.channel.send(word)
```

Comment: Hi Eric. 
Thanks for your answer. 
I added await fun(discord.Context(message=message), word) and that is error: module 'discord' has no attribute 'Context'. 
By the way I know that I can send message normally but it is just example and my code is much more bigger and I m using this function few times in code so it is more efficient to create function. 
And I have new question: Is any way to use ctx in on_message?

Comment: Try `commands.context`. Generally using context in `on_message` is unnecessary. You have `message.channel.send`, `message.channel`, `message.guild`, and of course `message` itself. If you want to execute commands inside of `on_message` you may want to just create a second function that the command invoker calls that you can do in `on_message`.

Comment: You should not be manually constructing `commands.Context` instead use `Bot.get_context` (it's a coroutine) which takes a `Message` as an argument, and returns a context

Comment: @Rose As I said, it's generally not a good idea to make them yourself. Although I believe your method is probably much more stable, I think `message.channel.send` will suffice. (it still basically does the same thing: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/discord/ext/commands/bot.py#L1211)

Comment: It still doesn't solve my problem. I'm annoyed and frustrated with this code. I wanted to be more profesional and use function instead copy and paste parts of code in program. I'm going to start it anew and try devise other way to overcome this problem.
Thank you all for your willingness help me.

Comment: This is in no way more professional and just adds unnecessary complexity. Forcing yourself to use `ctx` every time is more bad practice than just sending it normally. I promise, everyone who reads your code will appreciate `message.channel.send` more.